# Importing an animation from Maya to a DirectX application?

Tags: animation, directx, maya

I am currently working on a game using DirectX. I have been working with the animations on this project for quite some time. It took me a while to notice, but I saw that my model and animation is flipped across the X axis when exported from Maya. I have tried seeking help in this matter, but the internet hasn't actually been very helpful. I have two questions. Is this a common problem? Is there an "easy" solution to solve this?

I have researched changing handedness in a matrix. That brought me to many debates where handedness is not shown in a matrix. Is this correct? I'm just not sure on how to approach this problem so any help on this matter would be grateful.

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Did you try multiplaying your model, or your animation matrices by a scaling matrix (Scaling(-1,0,0)). This will invert all the x coordinates. Your complete transformation should be = model * scaling(-1,0,0) * animation * worldviewproj.